# Can biber resolve XData only, not CrossRef

Tags: cross-referencing, biber

I have a biblatex database (flat file) with `XData` entries and with entries containing `XData` and/or `CrossRef` fields. I would like to convert this into a database where the `XData` references are resolved, but not the `CrossRef` references.

I know that `biber --tool --resolve` resolves both `XData` and `CrossRef` (by default) and know how to then remove `XData` entries. However, I do not know how to just resolve `XData`, not `CrossRef` and neither did I find any information about that in the biber man page or on-line.

Is it possible to use biber (in tool mode, I guess) to only resolve `XData` references? If yes, how? If no, what would be an alternative approach.

[I am using biber 2.5.]

Comment: I don't think that can be done at the moment (I didn't find anything in the docs about it), but I might be wrong. If nothing turns up in due time, you might want to write a feature request https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: I have now done it manually, but I think the functionality is also more generally useful than just for me, so I'll leave this open. I've created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/172.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this get an answer: Following the feature request https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/172, Biber 2.8 and later support the three options

- `--output-resolve-xdata`,
- `--output-resolve-crossrefs` and
- `--output-resolve-sets`

to resolve `xdata`,  `crossrefs` and `set` relations, respectively, as well as the meta option `--output-resolve` that sets all three at the same time.